# ArrayList - searching for the most common integer

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 999 numbers in my arrayList, some of the numbers are repeated. And i want to find the most frequent number in the list, what is the most efficient way of doing that?

Comment: what do you mean by not using hashmap? is the binary  search tree good for you ?

Comment: Is the range of the values known?

Comment: You certainly *could* find it without using a HashMap, but what are you trying to achieve? If it's efficiency - what is the distribution of the numbers? You need to give more information.

Comment: yes i got all the integers from a text file from the range of 0 to 100

Comment: I would recommend checking that question: [Algorithm for 'k'' most frequently occurring numbers][1]


  [1]: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1321/algorithm-for-k-most-frequently-occurring-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two simple implementations with different complexity (of course if you have only a few numbers performance gain is symbolic) :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    static AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer> getMostFrequentN2(ArrayList<Integer> values)
    {
        ArrayList<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>> frequencies = new ArrayList<>();

        int maxIndex = 0;

        main:
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
        {
            int value = values.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < frequencies.size(); ++j)
            {
                if (frequencies.get(j).getKey() == value)
                {
                    frequencies.get(j).setValue(frequencies.get(j).getValue() + 1);

                    if (frequencies.get(maxIndex).getValue() < frequencies.get(j).getValue())
                    {
                        maxIndex = j;
                    }

                    continue main;
                }
            }

            frequencies.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>(value, 1));
        }

        return frequencies.get(maxIndex);
    }

    static AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer> getMostFrequentNLogN(ArrayList<Integer> values)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList(values);

        Collections.sort(tmp);

        AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer> max = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(0, 0);

        int current = tmp.get(0);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (tmp.get(i) == current)
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (count > max.getValue())
                {
                    max = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>(current, count); 
                }

                current = tmp.get(i);

                count = 1;
            }
        }

        if (count > max.getValue())
        {
            max = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>(current, count); 
        }

        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList(99);

        for (int i = 0; i < 99; ++i)
        {
            numbers.add((int)(Math.random() * 10));
        }

        System.out.println(numbers);

        System.out.println(getMostFrequentN2(numbers));
        System.out.println(getMostFrequentNLogN(numbers));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort the list  and than count which occurs the most by reading the sorted List.

Needs *0(n log n)* Time

```
1 3 6 1 82 42 11 42 1 42 3 42
```

sorted

```
1 1 1 3 3 6 11 42 42 42 42 82
```

Read the list from left to right and remember which value was seen the most so far and how often

Answer (score 1):

I assume, as you wrote in comment, that you read numbers from 0 to 100 
from a text file, so you can use

```
int[] count = new int[101];
...
count[numberJustRead]++;
...
```

and after read all numbers

```
int max = 0;
int maxIndex = 0; //this is what you looking for
for(int i = 0, k = count.length; i < k; i++){
  if(count[i] > max){
    max = count[i];
    maxIndex = i;
  }
}
```

or you maybe like guava's [Mulitset](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, slowly.

You could do this with a List of Lists; an inner list contains the numbers you have seen, and the index of the outer list is the number of occurrences.  So after processing "1,2,1,3,1,2,3,4" you would have

```
[ [4], [2, 3], [1] ]
```

Once you are done processing the input list, you can get the last inner list contained by the highest index of the outer list, which in this case is `[1]`.  All elements in that list are tied for the maximum number of occurrences.